# Issue in execution of python code using event synthesis for speech translation

Tags: azure, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, speech

```
from_language = 'fr-FR'
to_language = 'en-US'

def synthesis_callback(evt):
    size = len(evt.result.audio)
    print(f'Audio synthesized: {size} byte(s) {"(COMPLETED)" if size == 0 else ""}')

    if size > 0:
        file = open('translation.wav', 'wb+')
        file.write(evt.result.audio)
        file.close()

def translate_speech_to_text():

    translation_config = speechsdk.translation.SpeechTranslationConfig(
            subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
    translation_config.speech_recognition_language = from_language
    translation_config.add_target_language(to_language)

    translation_config.voice_name = "en-US-JennyNeural"
    audio_input = speechsdk.AudioConfig(filename=filename)

    recognizer = speechsdk.translation.TranslationRecognizer(translation_config=translation_config, audio_config = audio_input )

    done = False

    def stop_cb(evt):
        """callback that stops continuous recognition upon receiving an event `evt`"""
        print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
        recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
        nonlocal done
        done = True

    # Connect callbacks to the events fired by the speech recognizer
    recognizer.recognizing.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZING: {}'.format(evt)))
    recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZED: {}'.format(evt)))
    recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
    recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))
    recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('CANCELED {}'.format(evt)))
    # stop continuous recognition on either session stopped or canceled events
    recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
    recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)

    # Start continuous speech recognition
    recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()

    while not done:
        time.sleep(.5)
    
translate_speech_to_text()
```

Issue description: I am trying to execute event synthesis example python code from Azure Cognitive Speech services documentation. Other subscription id and locale, I have changed function from recognize_once() to start_continuous_recognition() in order to read entire audio file. But it is not generating any output .wav file. I have tried start_continuous_recognition_async() function but its not working too.

I would like to know do I need to anything more to synthesize audio from one language to another?

Answer (score 0):

The voice name "en-US-Hedda" does not exist. Please use one of the supported voice names mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support#text-to-speech

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have 
some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the 
target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks Darren. I changed the voice names. But I am still having issues in translation of input audio.